# Creating a safe rest-api token in php and passing it to javascript

Tags: php, rest, security

I have a php web server with some user accounts and a java program running on another machine with a image related rest-api. The web server and the program are not really connected to each other.

Now I want to extend the api, and add a web page that gives logged-in users access to some functionality of the new api, with distinction for every user. So when the site loads php should insert into JavaScript code a kind of token that can be used with the username to somehow authenticate this specific user.

One way I thought about is to share a long enough password between the web server and the program, and generate tokens in php like this:

```
token = hash(password + username)
```

JavaScript would then send this token and the username with every request to the rest-api. The api could easily authenticate the user by generating the hash again, and comparing it to the one received. 
But as every user can retrieve his own token or even create multiple accounts and get a bunch of them, can I assume that it's impossible to figure out the secret password from the tokens? I have a feeling this is not secure enough.

Are there some better ways to do this? Or is this not possible without connecting the web server and the program?

Comment: Are you confusing JAVA and Javascript? They are definitely not the same beastie

Comment: I would recommend looking into JWT generation and OAuth specifications https://oauth.net/2/

Comment: @RiggsFolly The rest-api is made in java. JavaScript is used to contact it from browser